# What is the difference between 广阔，宽阔，宽广 and 辽阔?

Tags: meaning, difference

They have very similar definitions

广阔 vast; wide; spacious; expansive; extensive; broad:

宽阔 broad; wide; roomy; spacious

宽广 broad; extensive; spacious; vast:

辽阔 vast; extensive

Comment: CCG：Adjectives and collocation.Adjectives also vary in their collocational capacity.Some like 大 and 新 are of such a general nature that they can be used with many noun headwords w/o too many restrictions. Many adjectives, however, are collocationally specific. In other words, particular adjectives tend to be linked with specific noun headwords. For example (a) attributively 严格：严格的规定，严厉：严厉的批评，严肃：严肃的气氛，严重：严重的后果（b）predicatively 严格：要求很严格，严厉：声音很严厉，严肃：态度很严肃，严重：事态很严重。Examples in dictionaries, esp. jukuu should supply information about collocation.

Comment: @user6065 lol what are you talking about?

Comment: it appears translations supplied agree with bkrs, there also find examples showing collocations, e.g. for 广阔 广阔的国土 a vast country
广阔的前景 broad prospects
广阔天地 a vast world; a place with broad prospects
交游广阔 have a wide acquaintance; have a large circle of friends
for definition of collocation see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 广阔 vast; wide; spacious; expansive; extensive; broad:

广= broad 阔= wide

**广阔 (broad)** mostly describe:

1. space - e.g 广阔空间 (broad space)
2. territory - e.g.  广阔领土 (broad territory)
3. area - e.g. 广阔面积 (broad area)

> 宽阔 broad; wide; roomy; spacious

宽= spacious 阔= wide

**宽阔 (spacious)** mostly describe:

1. space  - e.g. 宽阔空间 (wide space); 宽阔房间 (spacious room)
2. object - e.g 车身宽阔 (the car is wide)

> 宽广 broad; extensive; spacious; vast:

宽= spacious 广 = broad

**宽广(expansive)** mostly describe:

1. space - e.g 宽广空间 (expansive space)
2. area - e.g 地方宽广(area is expansive)

> 辽阔 vast; extensive

辽= distant = 阔= wide

**辽阔 (vast)** mostly describe:

1. space  - e.g.  辽阔空间 (vast space)
2. territory - e.g.  辽阔领土 (vast territory )
3. area - e.g. 地方辽阔 (area is vast)

Maria Efremova wrote:

> *Is there any difference in usage between 广阔 and 辽阔?*

广阔 is more general, It can be used to describe area in a grand scale, for example: '广阔的宇宙'(wide universe) but it can also be used to describe area in much smaller scale, for example:  '广阔的足球场' (wide football field)

It can also be used metaphorically. For example 心胸广阔 (forgiving).

辽阔 is more specific. It is exclusively for describing area in a grand scale. (area that cover vast distance and require long time to travel)

辽 itself means 'distant' (far away in time or space)

you can say '辽阔的宇宙' (vast universe) but you cannot say '辽阔的足球场' (vast football field) because it is too small in scale.

Comment: Is there any difference in usage between 广阔 and 辽阔?

Comment: 广阔 is more general, it can be used metaphorically. For example 心胸广阔 (forgiving). It can also be used to describe comparatively smaller scale area, like  广阔的足球场 (wide football field);  辽阔 is more specific for area or space of grandest scale. Area that cover vast distance and require long time to travel.  辽 itself means 'distant' ( far away in time or space)